# Дата изменения/добавления строки в google tables

Tags: google-docs

Как реализовать в google docs excel добавление в строку времени изменения или добавления новой строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
var idRow = e.range.getRow();
//если внесены изменения в 3 колонку  
if ( idCol == 3 && sheet.getName() =='Лист1' ) {

var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

//добавить в первую и вторую дату и время
sheet.getRange(idRow, 1).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 2).setValue(varnow);

}
  if ( idCol == 7 && sheet.getName() =='Лист1' ) {
  var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

//добавить в первую и вторую дату и время
sheet.getRange(idRow, 8).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 9).setValue(varnow);

}
}

// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
}

function getTime() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'HH:mm');
}
```

Comment: если быстро вбивать новые значения в столбеец или копипастить сразу в нескоклько клеток в стобце, то function onEdit(e) не успевает отрабатывать. Не смог придумать выхода, кроме как попросить пользователей редактировать ячейки строго по одной в столбце и после ввода немного ждать.

Comment: Я совсем чайник. Попробовал Ваш скрипт. Он отрабатывает, но... [Есть проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1112168/15479).

Comment: Проконсультируйте, пожалуйста, по похожей задаче: нужно автоматически проставлять дату при любых изменениях в строке на листе Google Sheets. Можно ли изменит ьвышеуказанный скрипт под эти требования?

Answer (score 1):

Небольшая переделка похожего скрипта, просто настраивать какие столбцы проверять и какие заполнять.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
var idRow = e.range.getRow();

  if ( sheet.getName() == 'условия' ){ //на каком листе
  var tcol = 12; //столбец который нами меняется
  var toffset = 1; //смотрим что в ближайшем столбце справа + слева -
  var trange = 13; //где вписываем
   }
  
    if ( sheet.getName() == 'Реестр 1' || sheet.getName() == 'Реестр 2'){ //на каком листе
  var tcol = 5; //столбец который нами меняется
  var toffset = -3; //смотрим что в ближайшем столбце справа + слева -
  var trange = 2; //где вписываем
   }

if ( idCol == tcol) {// проверка столбца который нами меняется
var Value = e.range.offset(0, toffset).getValues(); // проверяем ячеку от вказаного выше сролбца
if ( Value == "" ) {

var vartoday = getDate();

sheet.getRange(idRow, trange).setValue( vartoday ); //где вписываем
}
}
}

// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy');// формат даты времени
}
```